# google authentication api for standalone application

Tags: java, authentication, google-api-java-client

I'm confused about google's authentication api. I want my application to have its own account and google drive (e.g. to use it as a database). Its google drive should be also accessible from web interface - for maintenance and debugging reasons (so service account is not an option). How should I log in? Which authentication type should i choose?

I don't want users to log in to their google accounts - they should not even know there is a google underneath.

Comment: Why not use a database with a web interface for the "debugging reasons"?  MySQL + phpMyAdmin is the default setup almost anywhere... simple to set up, easy to secure, and probably a lot less coding than Google Drive API

Comment: because gDrive gives me thousands things that i would have to implement by myself when using database. but architecture is not the problem. i have a trouble with google authentication api and i provided more general view on the application to avoid any confusions and receive better answers